# Run file with Sandboxie using autoit

Tags: autoit

My path of file is C:\Documents and Settings\12313\My Documents\Downloads\Bubble_Hit_TSA31DIBX.exe

I wanna run it with sandboxie but anytime redownload,the name of file is changing.
For example:Buble_Hit_******.exe " * " is the changing.

Comment: Will there only ever be 1 file called `Buble_Hit_**.exe` in the folder you download to? That would make life a lot easier.

Comment: Yes!!cause anytime i clear the sandboxie it will be delete too.In that folder only 1 file .exe when i start working and i wanna run that .exe file.i was try this .bat:
 for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /s *.exe') do (
    start "" "%%a"
 )

but it's just working when i run it's by click in that path.i cant run from another way like cmd or Run("...") on autoit. that not working...plz help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wildcard feature of [FileFindFirstFile](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileFindFirstFile.htm) and [FileFindNextFile](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileFindNextFile.htm) to do this easily from AutoIt. The helpfile for those functions contains an example of enumerating over a set of files that match the pattern, but you are only interested in the first, so only have to call `FileFindNextFile` once.

I would implement it as a function like the following:

```
; Returns the matching file name.
; If the file could not be found then return an empty string and sets @error to 1
Func _FindFile($wildcard)
    Local $hSearch = FileFindFirstFile($wildcard)
    If $hSearch = -1 Then Return SetError(1, 0, "")

    Local $ret = FileFindNextFile($hSearch)
    Local $found = Not @error
    FileClose($hSearch)

    If Not $found Then Return SetError(1, 0, "")
    Return $ret
EndFunc   ;==>_FindFile
```

Which would then be called like this (to find `Program Files (x86)`):

```
MsgBox(0, "Test", _FindFile("C:\Program Files (*)"))
```

Once you have the file name then `Run(...)` etc. etc. the rest of it should be fairly normal stuff you can find the helpfile.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!

MsgBox(0, "Test", _FindFile("C:\Sandbox\12313\DefaultBox\user\current\My Documents\iMacros\Downloads\*"))

It's show me a test box and name of the file i need to run. But How can i run that file automate.I just need to Run any file in that path(normaly 1 file) once a time when i run this script.

Comment: Ok, then I would use code something like [this](http://pad.mattdiesel.co.uk/run-file-with-sandboxie). This sort of code is already well covered in the AutoIt helpfile.

Comment: @user3503869, works for me, if I change the directory and file pattern to something on my system. You will have to debug it yourself from here.

Comment: That's very useful infor for me to debug.It's done. Thanks again for ur help!